# Parsing appointments from shared Outlook calendars

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to create an anonymized schedule for the conference rooms on our floor via Excel VBA.

The source data is stored in different Outlook calendars (every room has its own) and I got access to them via the "shared calendar" functionality of Outlook.

The problem I am currently having is fully automating the data retrieval process. I got everything else working fine, however, it requires the user to manually select the (currently) five different calendars from a small pop-up window, which is rather tiresome.

I have tried using the `GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items` approach, but this only seems to work for the local calendar not shared ones from the network (Exchange).

Is there a way to address these room calendars directly so that I can automate my process?

best regards,

daZza

Here's my current code, cut down to the relevant parts:

```
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

For x = 1 To 5

    Set myCalItems = olNS.PickFolder.Items

    With myCalItems
        .Sort "[Start]", False
        .IncludeRecurrences = True
    End With

    StringToCheck = "[Start] >= " & Quote(StartDate & " 12:00 AM") & " AND [End] <= " & Quote(EndDate & " 11:59 PM")

    Set ItemstoCheck = myCalItems.Restrict(StringToCheck)

    ' Do stuff with every item in "ItemstoCheck"
    ' ...
    ' ...
    ' ...

Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into the Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder method?

Comment: Thanks, I haven't seen this one yet. The documentation says that in `GetSharedDefaultFolder(Recipient, FolderType)` both arguments are required. How can I get the recipient argument, i.e. the owner of the folder / calendar?

Comment: You can call Namespace.CreateRecipient passing the name of the mailbox owner.

Comment: I see that, but how do I know who the owner is? Is there a way to get this via VBA or do I need to call the tech guys so they can figure out who the "owner" is?

Comment: The owner is the Exchange user whose mailbox you want to see. Do you not know that in advance? If the delegate mailbox was already added to the current profile, you can loop through all stores in the Namespace.Stores collection and call Store.GetDefaultFolder for each delegate store.